# Material UI Radio button group default multiple values selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
<RadioButtonGroup
    name={currentQuestion.id.toString()}
    onChange={this.onRadioBtnClick}
    valueSelected={answerObject ? answerObject.answer : ''}
 >
```

Hey, my question is; I'm aware that the prop valueSelected selects the radio button for that particular value. but i was wondering how to select multiple radio buttons. what would be the prop or logic for that?
thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews yes. i upvoted it.

Comment: Don't forget to check it as answered. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material UI will not allow you to select multiple radio buttons, if nothing else, for the simple reason of a radio button group should allow for only one selection at a time.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radiogroup)...

> A group of radio buttons. Only one radio button inside the group can
>   be selected at a time.

And the Material UI library `updateRadioButtons` method confirms this is impossible...

```
updateRadioButtons(newSelection) {
  if (this.state.numberCheckedRadioButtons === 0) {
    this.setState({selected: newSelection});
  } else {
    warning(false, `Material-UI: Cannot select a different radio button while another radio button
      has the 'checked' property set to true.`);
  }
}
```

I would recommend using a checkbox for multiple selections.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RadioButtonGroup name="Relations" style={{ display: 'flex' }} 
  valueSelected={this.props.RELATIONSHIP_ID}    
  value={this.props.RELATIONSHIP_ID}
  onChange={this.handleRadioButtonToggle}>
{
  this.props.relations.map( (key, index) => (
    <RadioButton value={key['RELATIONSHIP_ID']} 
    label={key['RELATIONSHIP_TYPE']}
    style={styles.radioButton}/>))
}
</RadioButtonGroup>
handleRadioButtonToggle=(e,value)=>{
console.log('radio',e,value)
}
```

Comment: You should add description.